# How to find multiple property values from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array of objects like,

```
customer1 = [
    {"key": "name",
     "value": "Peter"},
    {"key": "age",
     "value": 23},
    {"key": "address",
     "value": "xyz St, abcd"},
    {"key": "points",
     "value": 234}
    ]
```

and I want to find say age and address from this object, what is the recommended and optimal way to do that? For real application, I might have 20-40 key-value objects in this array, out of which I might want to access 5-10 values.

What I do right now is I loop through this object and use conditions to find and assign values to my variables. but in this approach, I have to write multiple else if expressions (5-10).

For example,

```
let name: string;
let points: number;

for (var item of customer1) {
    if (item.key === "name") {
        name = item.value;
    } else if (item.key === "points") {
        points = item.value;
    }};
```

Comment: As you noticed, this data format is not convenient. Can you change it or massage the data to a regular JS object (akin to `const customer1 = { name: "Peter", age: 23, address: "xyz St, abcd", points: 234 }` on the boundary of your app?

Comment: @rohitkumar Did you get a chance to look into the answer I added ? I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal Yes. thanks. your answer is exactly what I was looking for. I actually responded to your answer with a similar comment, but I don't see it now. (It may have been deleted by moderation).

Comment: @rohitkumar Thanks! Can you please accept the answer if it helps so that it will be helpful for other developers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve this requirement with the help of [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const customer1 = [
  { "key": "name", "value": "Peter" },
  { "key": "age", "value": 23 },
  { "key": "address", "value": "xyz St, abcd" },
  { "key": "points", "value": 234 }
];

const searchKeys = ['age', 'address'];

const res = customer1.filter(obj => searchKeys.includes(obj.key)).map(({ value}) => value);

const [age, address] = res;

console.log(age);
console.log(address);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will always have to write explicitly `"name"`, `"points"`,... because you can't parse string value and use it to identify variable with the same name.
But to avoid using multiple else if, maybe the switch case statement is more appropriate and readable?

```
interface CustomerProperty {
    key: string,
    value: string | number
}

let customer1: CustomerProperty[] = [
    {
        "key": "name",
        "value": "Peter"
    },
    {
        "key": "age",
        "value": 23},
    {
        "key": "address",
        "value": "xyz St, abcd"},
    {
        "key": "points",
        "value": 234
    }
];

let nameValue: string;
let pointsValue: number;
for (var item of customer1) {
    switch (item.key) {
        case "name":
            nameValue = item.value as string;
            break;
        case "points":
            pointsValue = item.value as number;
            break;
    }
};
```